# Operador composto de atribuição

Tags: php, operadores, matemática

Não consigo entender o porque ele não executa a expressão que eu quero.

Segue o código:

```
$i = 1; $ranking = 1; $r = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++){
    $p = isset($_GET["n$i"])?$_GET["n$i"]:0;
    echo "$ranking ° Numero: $p";
    $r += $p;
    $ranking++;
}

echo "A Multiplicação dos numeros é igual a : $r"
```

A linha principal do código é `$r += $p;`, ele vai somando as variáveis e exibe na variável `$r`, até ai tudo bem, porem se alterar para `$r *= $p;` ou para `$r /= $p;` o resultado sempre vai ser 0 (*ZERO*), porque?

Comment: **PS:** está faltando um ; (ponto e vírgula) na última linha do código também.

Comment: A sim, devo ter tirado no copy+paste, Obrigado ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quanto é 0 multiplicado por qualquer valor? É 0, certo? Então está explicado. Matemática pura.

Quanto é 0 divido por qualquer valor? Também 0.

Programação segue as regras matemáticas.

Se colocar 1 em `$r` pode sair alguma coisa na multiplicação, mas provavelmente não é o que deseja. Na divisão provavelmente seria melhor outro valor, mas não parece que trocar o operador faça sentido neste código. Inclusive ele provavelmente pode ser simplificado, pelo que foi apresentado.

Se tivesse um contexto maior eu poderia melhorar mais, mas já fica melhor assim:

```
$r = 0;
for ($ranking = 1; $ranking <=5; $ranking++) {
    $p = isset($_GET["n$ranking"])?$_GET["n$ranking"]:0;
    echo "$ranking ° Numero: $p";
    $r += $p;
}
```

Tinha variáveis desnecessárias aí.

Se quer multiplicar:

```
$r = 1;
for ($ranking = 1; $ranking <=5; $ranking++) {
    $p = isset($_GET["n$ranking"])?$_GET["n$ranking"]:0;
    echo "$ranking ° Numero: $p";
    $r *= $p;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Compound.php).

Eu nem falei que esse código tem sérios problemas de segurança porque pega um dado que vem de fora e confia que ele estará certinho. Mas isso é outro assunto.

Comment: A questão é, se a variável $p recebe 4 vezes o numero 5, isso é.. 5 5 5 5
com o operador $r += $p; o resultado ficará 20 correto?
porem, caso eu altere para $r *= $p; o resultado ficará 0.
Não estou testando simplificações nem nada, só estou testando essa linguagem nova  que estou aprendendo.

Comment: Não sei do que está falando.

Comment: acabei de editar o comentário, enviei ele pela metade, se possível leia acima novamente por favor. thanks

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu sabia que algo estava errado, e que eu não estava enchergando, sempre bom ter mais de um programador para conferir o código. ^^
Alterei as linhas:
$i = 1; $ranking = 1; $r = 1;
echo "A Multiplicação dos numeros é igual a : ".($r-1);

Comment: Estou aprendendo ainda PHP, como disse acima, muito obrigado pelas dicas.
poderia me mostrar a maneira simplificada desse código?

Comment: @NicolasGuilherme editei e coloquei a forma simplificada

Comment: Obrigado, acabei de ver, postei a minha versão também antes de você postar a sua, a variável ranking estava desnecessária mesmo, é que estava fazendo outros testes e acabou que deixei ela lá.
Meu erro foi não perceber que inicializei a variável $r com 0(ZERO), depois desse seu grande toque, tudo fez sentido.

Com relação a segurança do código, eu nunca estudei sobre segurança, assim que terminar meus estudos sobre a sintax dessa linguagem, vou começar a estudar sobre a segurança do código.
Obrigado pelo toque, e pelos exemplos, vai ajudar quem venha a ter a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Pra quem tiver Dúvidas, o código ficou assim.

```
$i = 1; $r = 1;
while($i <=5) {
    $p = isset($_GET["n$i"])?$_GET["n$i"]:0;
    echo "$i ° Numero: $p <br>";
    $r *= $p;
    $i++;
}


echo "<br>A Multiplicação dos numeros é igual a : ".($r-1);
```

Comment: O código do bigown não funcionou? A unica coisa que parece que mudou foi o $r-1 no final.

Comment: Oi, não tinha visto o código dele ainda, esta a mesma coisa que o meu, porém com a estrutura de repetição for, e a variável ranking eu retirei do código.

Comment: Entendi, a edição dele ocorreu depois, porem a sua resposta não foi explicada por isso achei a do bigown melhor, nada contra a sua, só que acho que para futuros visitantes a outra resposta será mais util. ;D

Comment: A sim, ele que me ajudou a tirar a duvida, ele merece ^^.